# What does this code mean?

Tags: command

```
#Create & update pid file
/usr/ucb/ps -axuwww | grep java | grep "SmartFileConvertor $instance" | grep -v grep | nawk '{ print $2 }' > ${pidFile}
```

Comment: It means the person who wrote it is clueless about scripting...

Comment: Yes, indeed.  Step back from the close-up view of this pipeline and what its components do, and one sees three major sins here not to copy.  [PID files are a mechanism that we have known to be faulty](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/unix-daemon-design-mistakes-to-avoid.html#DoNotCreatePIDFiles) since the 1980s.  [`grep`ping the output of `ps` is wrongheaded](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#The_risk_of_parsing_the_process_tree).  And [`grep` piped into `awk` is a Useless Use of `grep`](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#grep).

Answer (score 3):

`ps -axuwww` :
`axu` : BSD syntax to list all the processes in the system
`www` : maximum width

Here is the full command which is run from left to right:
`/usr/ucb/ps -axuwww | grep java` : output only lines containing "java"

**..**`| grep "SmartFileConvertor $instance"` : output only lines containing "SmartFileConvertor" with some instance value set as an environment variable

**..**`| grep -v grep` : output only lines that don't include "grep"

**..**`| nawk '{ print $2 }'` : output the second column which is the pid

**..**`> ${pidFile}` : redirect the output to the file with the name inside the `pidFile` environment variable

When you want to know the parameters of a command / program, a `man page` is usually available with the `man` command such as `man ps` and `man grep`.

Comment: Suppose there is a Jennifer A. Vasquez whose username is `javasquez`. Her processes will be picked up by `grep java`, as will any process _called_ `java` or even `javac`.  `grep` will find matches anywhere in the line, not just from a single column